# How to deploy database on unit testing

Tags: database, unit-testing, deployment, integration-testing

I have to run integration unit tests (NOT DATABASE TEST). My project is in Visual Studio 2010.

I also have Database Project setup.

1. How can I deploy the database before running integration or unit tests?
2. How can I deploy the database when building the solution in tfs 2010?

Please help

Comment: Nitpick: There are integration tests and there are unit tests. There is no such thing as integration unit tests. You can run integration tests using a unit test framework, but they are still integration tests.

Comment: Ok, integration test, I mean integration tests. I wrote the upper, because if I had written unit test, someone would say that the db mus be mocked up. But I need to test all the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

We're using Visual Studio 2010 for application and database development.  We have tried having the database as a project within the application solution and having independent solutions.  We ended up keeping them separated.  We deploy the database to our development environments directly from visual studio using the "Deploy Solution" option.  The database project properties has "Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database" option on the Deploy tab.  This will deploy the database to which ever environment is configured. It's a manual step.

When the database project is part of the solution with application project(s) it gets deployed as part of the rest of the project.

The real work was in getting continuous integration working so that any time either project has a check-in they will be built, tested and deployed to the CI environment.  We decided to go ahead and unit test our stored procedures in the database project.

The build agent calls the command line vsdbcmd with our particular set of parameters to deploy the databse to the CI environment.

Comment: So you're using the vsdbcmd to automatically deploy the database scripts. We'll give it a try. Thanks